Solving a convolution of two discrete probabilities
I have two discrete probability spaces.
A (a 6 sided die):
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
\frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6}& \frac{1}{6}& \frac{1}{6}& \frac{1}{6}& \frac{1}{6}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
B (a uniform distribution of random numbers):
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
7 &  15 & 30 & 60\\
\frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
I want some help determining the probability of the distribution space of the sum of A, B. In other words, a table for all z in Z such that:
$$
P(Z=z) = \sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}P(A=a)*P(B=z-a)
$$
I found this resource about convolutions in an introductory textbook here.
I've used numpy to try to find a solution:
A = [1/6]*6
B = [1/4]*4
np.convolve(A, B)
>>> array([0.04166667, 0.08333333, 0.125     , 0.16666667, 0.16666667,
       0.16666667, 0.125     , 0.08333333, 0.04166667])

but this seems to be counting that $Z(z=9) = P(A=2)P(B=7) + P(A=1)P(B=15) = \frac{2}{24}$, which I don't believe is correct (9 isn't the same as 1 + 15 = 16)
Is there something wrong with my approach to calculating the probability space? I'm thinking that perhaps to calculate the entire probability space, I'll have to do a pairwise multiplication, in other words a $O(n^2)$ brute force solution where I have to look at each pair and calculate the probability. If that's correct, is there a faster algorithm?

The minimum sum is $7+1=8$ and maximum sum is $60+6=66$. The valid ranges are $8$ to $13$, $16$ to $21$, $31$ to $36$ and $61$ to $66$. The probabilities at these is the convolution of the two sequence. The probabilities at values except these $24$ will be $0$.

Please elaborate, in very clear detail, how having a 1 from A and a 15 from B leads to the result of 9.  I don't understand this.

@user2661923 My original intention was to put a hypothesis as to why numpy was returning a result of 2/24 at index = 1. The guess is that it was counting, A(a = 1)*B(b=15) ["index 1" of A, with "index 2" of B of the original probability space] + A(a = 2) * B(b= 7) ["index 2" of A * "index 1" of A of the original probability space].

@Srini If I'm understanding correctly, are you suggesting that I go through the valid ranges and do a convolution as a pairwise multiplication of probabilities? That feels like this becomes that $n^2$ bruteforce solution within the valid ranges

If your range did not have holes, the length of convolution of sequences of length $m$ and $n$ is $m+n-1$. However, you have holes in your $B$. So those 24 non-zero values I mentioned come into picture. Convolution is readily available in most math packages (what algorithms behind them are not known to me). I wonder why you need to do it manually one computation at a time

You have ignored the holes in $B$. In your code, try adding zeroes for the holes in the ranges of B. You will get the correct answer
